# Xcode 9 can't find header from built-in framework, but it exists there

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS project, it can be compiled with Xcode 8.

I updated Xcode to 9 recently, it can't be compiled with errors below:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CIImage.h:16:9: 'IOSurface/IOSurfaceRef.h' file not found

I noticed `IOSurface` is needed, so I added `IOSurface.framework` in `Build Phases`, but I still got this error.

In project hierarchy, `IOSurface.framework` is in `Frameworks` folder, `IOSurfaceRef.h` is there after expanding this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this problem is coming from thirdparty, their sdk has a framework names `IOSurface.framework`, that's why headers can't be found.